# Django Settings.py - SECRET_KEY - KeyError

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

Currently have a *Django* project running on Python 3.6.9, hosted on *Digital ocean* using *Gunicorn* and *Nginx*.

I am attempting to switch my `SECRET_KEY` and other passwords to **environment variables** opposed to having them as a string in `settings.py`.

When doing so I run into the following error and Gunicorn shuts down.

```
Dec 10 15:22:20:   File "/home/user/projectdir/project/project/settings.py", line 23, in <module>
Dec 10 15:22:20 droplet_name gunicorn:     SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
Dec 10 15:22:20 droplet_name gunicorn:   File "/home/user/projectdir/myenv/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
Dec 10 15:22:20 droplet_name gunicorn:     raise KeyError(key) from None
Dec 10 15:22:20 droplet_name gunicorn: KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
Dec 10 15:22:20 droplet_name gunicorn: [2019-12-10 15:22:20 +0000] [20022] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 20022)
```

I have exported the `SECRET_KEY` correctly prior by doing

`export SECRET_KEY='my_key'`

This is what my `settings.py` looks like as well:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["my_ip"]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project_name.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project_name.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'projectnamedb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

LOGIN_URL = '/home/user_login'
```

I have read through at least a dozen similar posts and still cannot correct the issue. I would like to use `os.environ` if possible without loading a new *library*.

UPDATE: I have placed a `test_one.py` document in the same directory as settings.py with the following code. When ran, it outputs the `SECRET_KEY` and returns a string as the type as expected. Still cannot achieve the same result on the `settings.py` file.

```
import os

print(os.environ['SECRET_KEY'])
print(type(os.environ['SECRET_KEY']))

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
print(type(SECRET_KEY))
```

Comment: Update: After days of trying different possible solutions I was unable to use the default os.environ solution I was searching for. Ended up solving the problem by using Django-Environ library to save the keys to a .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I additionally converted the value of the environment variable to a string. Then it worked for me. My guess is that, depending on which special characters your Private Key contains, there may be problems reading the environment variable:

```
SECRET_KEY = str(os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY'))
```